# Ghostscript - create a pdf with multiple identical pages and keep size down

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Im trying to use Ghostscript to create a PDF with multiple identical pages. I will later use this together with another multipaged PDF to stamp on unique information onto every page.

Is it possible to use Ghostscript to create such a PDF and keep the size of the final file down? Maby there is a flag that i have not noticed that can do this in a better way than the script below?

I have tried to use a regular merge command like the one below but the size of the resulting PDF grows alot and the original file size of 2,061kb merged to a 100page pdf results in a final size of 46,117kb.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64.exe"^
 -dBATCH^
 -dNOPAUSE^
 -q^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite^
 -sOutputFile=outputpdf.pdf^
 "inputpdf.pdf"^
 "inputpdf.pdf"^
 "inputpdf.pdf"(and so on 100 times)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `-dPDFFitPage` to your command.

This is from documentation:

> Rather than selecting a PageSize given by the PDF MediaBox, BleedBox (see -dUseBleedBox), TrimBox (see -dUseTrimBox), ArtBox (see -dUseArtBox), or CropBox (see -dUseCropBox), the PDF file will be scaled to fit the current device page size (usually the default page size)